# Block script in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blocking

I have a fancy script that is nice, but not essential and surprise surprise, doesn't play nice with IE.
How do I 'comment it out' for IE?

I know I can use the following to *include* statements for IE, but how do I *exclude* them?

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can use the server side to detect if an IE browser is making the request and then not send that script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use ! [see here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#syntax)

```
<!--[if !IE]>
```

or

```
<!--[if !(IE 6)]>
```

Comment: Wow I thought it would be simple, but not that easy! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

For all IE versions:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
conditional stuff
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no such mechanism as to exclude a script (i.e. unless the script is targeted at IE only, in which case go see ramblex/karim79's answer).

But ... you could modify your script to check for a global (yeah, I know *sigh*) variable that - when set - makes the script stop. Something along the line:

```
// wrap your nice script in an anonymous function
(function(document, undefined) {
    if ( window.ie6 === true ) return;

    .....
})(document);
```

Now go on and include the global variable with a conditional tag, like so:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    window.ie6 = true;
<![endif]-->
```

Et voila.