# Only run script if not Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

How would I go about running a script in every browser except for Internet Explorer?

I'm using queryloader2 on my site, and (for whatever reason) it takes around a minute to load in IE9, I'm assuming the same or worse in older versions of IE. In any other browser, it's just a few seconds. Due to this, I'd like to just not have the script run at all in any version of IE (it doesn't truly hurt the functionality of the site).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357458/block-script-in-ie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional comments in all the other answers (at the time of this posting) are incorrect, and will be interpreted as either (invalid) HTML or completely ignored as an HTML comment in non-IE browsers.

It is important to understand that as far as any browser other than IE is concerned (and even newer versions of IE), the "conditional HTML comment" is just a comment. In other words, something like the upvoted answer's suggestion:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is, as far as anything other than IE is concerned, just one long comment, starting at the `<!--` on line 1 and ending at the `-->` on line 3, just like any other HTML comment.

To get a chunk of HTML to be ignored by IE, you have to take advantage of the fact that HTML comments do not support nesting, i.e. `<!-- <!-- --> something -->` is a comment that ends at the *first* `-->` and not the second, meaning `something -->` will be parsed as HTML and not considered part of the comment.

So what we can do is use something like this instead:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Here, non-IE browsers will see two separate comments (on the 1st and 3rd lines, respectively) and regular HTML in the middle. But a browser parsing these tags will see a comment starting on the first line, *then ignore everything until encountering* `<![endif]-->` on the 3rd line. This gives us a block of code that will be executed by non-IE/modern browsers, but will be ignored by old versions of IE supporting conditional HTML.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use conditional comments for that:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script src="myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I thought that doing this made the script only work in IE, as opposed to only not working in IE? 
Oops guess not, thanks!

Comment: Note the `!` symbol. Without it script will be loaded only in IE. With it in all browsers except IE

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot mate! Sorry for asking a stupid question, I should have realized that earlier.

Comment: You are missing the closing comment for the initial script tag. Without it, the entire thing will appear as a comment block to non-IE browsers.

Answer (score -2):

below code is may be fine but unfortunately not working in my problem,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,so if above code is not working , then use this

```
<![if !IE]>You are NOT using IE.<![endif]
```

Comment: You can't use that; it will be interpreted as invalid HTML by other browsers. It must be in a comment block.